# Why does my search engine switch to Bing? (Browser redirect)

Tags: google-chrome, bing

Using Windows 10 Home.  I have Google set as the default search engine (see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0WIw.png)).  However, when I enter a search term in the address bar, Google returns some results, which are cleared about 1 second later, and the same search is run with Bing (see image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmJy1.png)).  How can I disable this Bing hijacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by a suggestion on BleepingComputer.com: Reset Chrome settings to default.

You can restore your browser settings in Chrome at any time. You might need to do this if apps or extensions you installed changed your settings without your knowledge. Your saved bookmarks and passwords won't be cleared or changed.

- On your computer, open Chrome.
- At the top right, click More >
  Settings.
- At the bottom, click Advanced.

  - Chromebook, Linux, and Mac: Under "Reset Settings," click Restore settings to their original defaults > Reset Settings.
  - Windows: Under "Reset and cleanup,” click 
    Reset Settings > Reset Settings.

Answer (score 3):

Please check browser extensions. There is probably malicious extension installed. Try to disable All of them and check.

Answer (score 0):

Look for Chrome extensions Clusite extension this was the issue I found when using Chrome and it would switch to Bing.  I removed this extension and it stopped switching to bing.

If you don't want to reset to default you can go to:
- Settings.
- Right side of settings open Extensions.
- Look for Clusite and select remove.